# How to save (all) SQL server image datatype to file system with correct file extension

Tags: sql, sql-server, image, binary, file-extension

I have different types of files in table (txt, doc, jpg, etc) and I want to save them all to my file system. I know how to do it file by file, but it's no use, I have to do a loop that saves all files with right extensions at once. Any advice?

I do it this way now:

```
DECLARE @ObjectToken INT
EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, <this is where binary data goes>
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, 'd:/file.txt', 2
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close'
EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken
```

So, my question would be is there a way to do this for all records (save all files) in db table at once and with setting the correct file extension for every saved file?

Comment: what are you asking exactly?

Comment: I'm asking how to save binary data (image datatype) from sql server database to file system as files.

Comment: your code looks like it's copied from http://heidibrebels.be/blog/archives/2011/save-image-sql-server-file-sql any reason you do not use the cursor part, too?

Comment: I didn't copy it from there so I didn't see the part with the cursor. Anyway, as I see on http://heidibrebels.be/blog/archives/2011/save-image-sql-server-file-sql it saves all files as .jpg, and I have a few different file extensions. 
Do you maybe know how to save each file with its own extension?

Comment: Apologies for my assumption. If you did not store the original file name and/or extension, there is no (easy) way retrieving them. You can however inspect the first bytes of the binary: .jpg starts with ff d8 ff e0 xx xx "JFIF", .png starts with xx "PNG" (xx = arbitrary hex value), etc

Comment: I have file name in other column, it is a complete path of the location from which the file is uploaded finishing with the file name and extension. Maybe I can get it from this column? Do you maybe know how to do that? 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem. As I found it is REALLY not easy to migrate db from SQL Server 2000 to 2005. Only solution which works is this one - http://tek-works.com/fixing-there-is-already-an-object-named-sysnsobjs-in-the-database/

After completing those steps you just have to set Compatibility  level to 90. (Right click on database > Properties > Compatibility level)

Then you can use VARBINARY(MAX) and save complete image datatype binary files to filesystem.

Good luck with migrating!

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [code I mentioned in the comments](http://heidibrebels.be/blog/archives/2011/save-image-sql-server-file-sql), AND assuming you use SQL Server 2005 or higher, this solution should work for you

```
DECLARE 
    @FileContent VARBINARY(MAX),
    @FileName VARCHAR(MAX),
    @ObjectToken INT,
    @FileID BIGINT

DECLARE cFiles CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT Id, FileName, Image_Data from MyFileTable
OPEN cFiles

FETCH NEXT FROM cFiles INTO @FileID, @FileName, @FileContent

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    -- CHOOSE 1 of these SET statements:

    -- if FileName is unique, then just remove special characters
    SET @FileName = REPLACE(REPLACE(@FileName, '\', ' '), ':', ' ')
    -- if FileName without path information is unique
    SET @FileName = SUBSTRING(@FileName,
        len(@FileName)+2-CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@FileName)),len(@FileName))
    -- if you just take ID + extensions
    SET @FileName = 'c:\path\to\' + CAST(@FileID AS varchar) + 
        SUBSTRING(@ap_description,len(@ap_description)+1
            -CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(@ap_description)),len(@ap_description))

    EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
    EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @FileContent
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @FileName, 2
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close'
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken

    FETCH NEXT FROM cFiles INTO @FileID, @FileName, @FileContent
END

CLOSE cFiles
DEALLOCATE cFiles
```

The `image` should be automatically cast to `varbinary(max)`.

(`'\'` breaks SO syntax highlighting.)

Comment: Unfortunately I use SQL Server 2000 so I can't use VARBINARY (MAX), VARCHAR(MAX)... Is there any other solution?
Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: In SQL Server 2000 you only have the possibility to use TEXTPTR and READTEXT. The single 'Write' call needs to be replaced by a loop chunking through the binary. See http://books.google.at/books?id=mxm2Szo3jckC&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=readtext+textptr+read+binary&source=bl&ots=z369qx5NFj&sig=l1JrXOakmncld10yUaCWuNLeF90&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qXpJUa7FCdDltQbfxoFQ&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=readtext%20textptr%20read%20binary&f=false and http://www.guidanceshare.com/wiki/ADO.NET_2.0_Performance_Guidelines_-_Binary_Large_Objects#Use_READTEXT_to_Read_from_SQL_Server_2000 for samples

Comment: Just one more question. Would it be easier to migrate db to SQL Server 2005 so I can use VARBINARY(MAX)?

Comment: it's definitely easier then