# Saving Image Data type to file system from SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm not SQL Server expert, just with some basic knowledge I'm trying to download the objects stored in SQL Server into the file system. I followed the below link, but I can't able to save the file. If I execute the program it's saying processed successfully but not seeing any files in the folder. The only thing I changed from the code mentioned in the link was

```
SET @FileName = 'G:\Path\Testing.doc'
```

Rest all of them I'm using the same code. Can someone please shed some light and provide solution for me?

[How to save (all) SQL server image datatype to file system with correct file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495925/how-to-save-all-sql-server-image-datatype-to-file-system-with-correct-file-ext)

Thanks
Justin.

Comment: And what's happening? Do you get an error? If so: **what is** the error?

Comment: I'm not getting any error. It says processed successfully. But im not seeing any files in the folder specified.BTW I'm running this in SQL server mgmt studio.

Comment: Where is your SQL Server running? On your own machine? On a separate server machine?

Comment: Marc,Thanks so much! I was such an Idiot. I was checking in my drive , but actually it got stored in the server. Thanks again!